# Throw a custom 401 HTTP Exception in Kohana

Tags: php, kohana, http-status-code-401, kohana-3.3, www-authenticate

When I throw a `HTTP_Exception_401` in `Kohana 3.3` I get the following error:

```
Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: A 'www-authenticate' header must be specified for a HTTP 401 Unauthorized
```

Now the obvious problem here is that the `www-authenticate` header hasn't been set.

What I'm struggling to figure out is how and where to set it.
I have tried the following but the same error is thrown:

Using native PHP `header()`:

```
header('WWW-Authenticate: realm="My Website"');
throw new HTTP_Exception_401('Authorisation Required');
```

Adding header to request object:

```
$this->request->header('WWW-Authenticate', 'realm="My Website"');
throw new HTTP_Exception_401('Authorisation Required');
```

I'm trying to throw the exception from a controller.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [upgrage guide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/upgrading) says:

```
// Unauthorized / Login Requied
throw HTTP_Exception::factory(401)->authenticate('Basic realm="MySite"');
```

Comment: Defining in the response didn't help... but using the `HTTP_Exception::factory()...` did. Cheers.